# jquery, onclick pegar valores id <a

Tags: jquery, ajax

É um sistema de notificações.
O código abaixo está funcionando bem.
Quando clico na notificação (

Arquivo php que gera as notificações:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="header">Você tem <?php echo $cont; ?> notificações</li>
      <li>
        <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
        <ul class="menu">
<!-- Notificações  -->
         <?php

            foreach(variavel as variavel):
                (...)
                print '
                      <li>
                        <a onclick="sendData()" href="#">
                          <i class="'.$icone.'"></i> '.$nome.'
                          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="'.$id.'">
                        </a>
                      </li>';


            endforeach;
         ?>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="footer"><a href="notif.php">Ver todas</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Função jquery/ajax:

```
<script>
function sendData()
{
    var idn = $('#id').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"upd.php",
        data: { id: idn },
        cache: false,
    });
}

</script>
```

Arquivo upd.php:

```
(...)
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE notif SET status = 1 WHERE id = :id";
(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta fazer assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.link-data').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var idn = $(this).children('input').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"upd.php",
            data: { id: idn },
            cache: false
        }); 
    });
});
```

Adiciona uma classe para identificar os links por exemplo `link-data`, outra coisa, coloca `id`s diferentes para cada `input`, o atributo `id` é para ser único na página. Espero que ajude, vlw.

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou.
No entanto, será que pode me auxiliar com outro problema que surgiu?

<li>
                                <a class="link-data" data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#'.$not_id.'">
                                  <i class="'.$not_icone.'"></i> '.$not_nome.'
                                <input type="hidden" name="idnot" id="'.$not_id.'" value="'.$not_id.'">
                                </a>
                              </li>';
Uso Bootstrap. A modal não está abrindo quando coloco o input dentro do 'a' ou 'li' ... só fora do dropmenu

Comment: Consegui. Graças ao código que você postou, que solucionou a dúvida inicial que perguntei.
Eu removi o input, coloquei uma classe na <li> pai, adicionei a variável id nela e alterei a linha no script: $(this).parent('li').attr('class');    CÓDIGO PHP:

<li class="'.$id.'">
                                <a class="link-data" data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#'.$id.'">
                                  <i class="'.$icone.'"></i> '.$nome.'
                                </a>
                              </li>

Grato Fernando.

Comment: Para abrir o modal tenta usar `$(seletor).click(function(){ $(seletor_do_modal).modal();});`. Com fica dentro do menu o evento que é disparado no click vai para o a função do menu, acho que seja isso.

Answer (score 0):

Eu sei que seria algo do tipo:

```
<script>
    $('.approved').on('click',function(){ 

        var taskid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

        $.ajax({ 
            url: './task.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: { action: 'aprovar', ID: taskid },
            success: function(data) { 
                window.location.reload(); 
            } 
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

Mas estou com dificuldade em adequar esse código.